# Fields are missing in GORM find method

Tags: go, go-gorm

Trying to get the value of the database table using the GORM method find, but it is not returning the values of all fields.
Table structure is,

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `newId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In the company.go, we have defined the company structure as,

```
package entities

import "time"

type Company struct {
    Id        string    `json:"id" gorm:"column:id;primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt" gorm:"column:createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updatedAt" gorm:"column:updatedAt"`
    Name      string    `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    NewId     string    `json:"newId" gorm:"column:newId"`
}
```

In the controller, companies.go, the data is fetched using the following code,

```
var companys []entities.Company
    result := db.Find(&companys)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, &result)
```

In the postman, it is only returning the values for the fields name and id. The rest of the fields the value is empty. What could be the issue?

I tried to fetch all the fields using find method of GORM, but it is only giving two fields

The data in the table looks like the following,
[image]

Comment: what does the data in the table look like?

Comment: @erik258 i have updated the coloumn image. please take a look

Comment: You're sure you're querying those fields in the query?  Better add that part of the Go code

Comment: this is all i have in the get method @erik258. I have used db.Select and it is not working for the missing fields

Comment: Show the Column names for the databas

Comment: Should you return `companys` instead of `&result`? `c.JSON(http.StatusOK, companys)`

Comment: That way it works like it should i.e returns all fields in JSON response

Comment: @Christoph included the screenshot. erased a field as it is confidential.

Comment: @Anatoly i did that as well, but the three fields are not showing up

Comment: The data: https://imgur.com/a/KA6Q960  The result: https://imgur.com/a/42nVQOC

Comment: Are the fields also nil or null before you convert it to json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the document [said](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html), the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` is managed by GORM, so could you leave its `gorm` tags?

> CreatedAt and UpdatedAt are special fields that GORM automatically populates with the current time when a record is created or updated.